# Question about Uniformly Continuous

Tags: real-analysis

How to show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(x+n)^{3/2}}$$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Show that $\frac{x^{2n}}{(x+n)^{3/2}}\leq \frac 1{n^{3/2}}$, hence the series is *_* (fill in the blank) convergent. What about the sum of a series of uniformly continuous functions which is __ (fill in the blank) convergent?

Comment: The title and question don't seem to match :-)

Comment: @Aryabhata I agree.

Comment: Anyway, here the series converges uniformly (Weistrass M-test similar to what you noted) and so the limit function is continuous, and since the interval is $[0,1]$, the function is uniformly continuous too. Not too familiar with normal convergence and I suppose it is possibly out of scope of a beginning calculus course.

Comment: Yes, in fact the dots can be also for uniformly.

Comment: On an intial reading, those dots seemed to indicate a pause for dramatic effect :-) and not something to be filled in!

Comment: You are right, I don't know how to do it in a more convenient way.

Comment: which is _________ convergent (fill in the blank)? (Using underscore character...)

Comment: @Aryabhata And all this time I was using "\underline{\phantom{Iwantittobethiswide}}"

Comment: ............. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[WolframAlpha](http://tinyurl.com/chtxc4x) says:

> $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(x+n)^{3/2}}= x^2 \Phi\left( x^2,\frac{3}{2},x+1 \right)$, when $|x|<1$. $\Phi(z,s,a)$ gives the [Hurwitz Lerch transcendent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html).